# Will an "update record" node within a flow trigger another record-triggered flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

Almost entirely covered by the title. Will an Update Records task within a Flow (A) trigger another Record-Triggered Flow (B), given that the update from A was such to meet the entry requirements of B?

In this specific case, A is separate from B, but both flows are after-save Record-Triggered flows. The Update Records task of flow A updates the same record that triggered flow A, and that I'm also looking to trigger flow B.

Note, this is essentially asking if Flows can cause chaining, without the use of the Subflow task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Record-triggered Flows](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/364118/record-triggered-flows)

Comment: @cropredy that seems very similar, but that question (if I'm reading correctly) seems to be the same record going through save cycles, rather than record(s) from an Update Records task.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to clarify -- are these before-save or after-save flows?  They're running on the same object, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked this myself this morning, and yes!

To be sure, I made a screen flow that runs from a button in my Quote object. This flow gets a value from the user and update the field in the Quote called Place.

Right after this screen flow ends, a record-triggered flow is fired because a change in the Place field is a start condition.

I hope I was helpful. Let me know.

Comment: By the way, the official documentation that goes over this is [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).